# trigger a click on loading the app

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to trigger a click on "Home" button on loading the app.
Home should become red and it should show the corresponding paragraph in rectangle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.showSingle').click(function () {
    $('.targetPara').hide();
    $('#p' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
    $('.showSingle').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');           
});    
});

var active_link = 1; // Change this value to set the active link
$('td[target='+active_link+']').trigger('click');
```

I an using the abobe jquery code.
Pls help me to figure out what is the prob

Comment: Is this the actual code? If so, you aren't triggering the event on `document` ready, so nothing will happen because the relevant `td` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `trigger` needs to be inside `document.ready`. You're accessing the DOM, so you have to wait for the browser to parse it. Also, make sure you set up the `click` event handler before you try to trigger the `click`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below selector doesn't have "showSingle" css class on it?

```
$('td[target='+active_link+']')
```

And what Abraham said (: